# Chainlink node: What to do when transactions are pending?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a chainlink node, and there are transactions that seem to be stuck. How can I fix pending outgoing confirmations?

[image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/592043790005567499/725936625821155328/unknown.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Most often, you did not fund your chainlink node account with gas. Go to your configration and grab the `ACCOUNT_ADDRESS` and send ETH to that address.

The second most common is that you're using an outdated version of the chainlink node. Please use 0.9.4 or higher.

---

### For pending Outgoing Confirmations:

1. You did not fund your chainlink node account with gas.
2. The ETH chain is clogged up.
3. Your `MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS` variable in your `.env` is too high (it gets set to a default)

If you see pending transactions at your oracle contracts address then it is likely #2. If you don't see any, it's likely #1.

If #1, you can just send some ETH to your node and it should be fine. You can find your node's address `ACCOUNT_ADDRESS` in the configuration page of your Chainlink GUI. [image: Chainlink node GUI Config page]

If #2 you can either:

1. You can delete the pending transactions from your database and hope everything clears up (This is an OK solution, hopefully smart contracts have a retry parameter for dealing with you data. But if your node stays stuck, then NO one will be able to get data. )

```
DELETE FROM job_runs WHERE status = 'pending_outgoing_confirmations';
DELETE FROM tx_attempts WHERE confirmed = 'f';
```

2. If you need those transactions to go through, you can [rebroadcast the transactions](https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/sending/checking-or-replacing-a-transaction-after-it-has-been-sent) with more ETH gas to push them through faster. This is a little trickier to do. The Chainlink nodes have a built in system to push transactions through without you having to do anything, so hopefully they will kick in.

If #3
Set or change your `MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS` and restart the node.

### For Pending Incoming Confirmations:

This is likely due to network congestion or you're working on a network that doesn't have many transactions. An easy fix is to reduce the number of incoming confirmations and restart your node.

In your `.env` file, add or set the following:

`MIN_INCOMING_CONFIRMATIONS=0`