# Why is The Chainlink Job Suspended?

Tags: ethereum, chainlink, brownie

I have a [chainlink job](https://gist.github.com/ee3220bf57e8f4b366a439220f1627ce) (vanilla http get, jsonparse) that is running OK and all tasks including `submit_tx` show a green "checkmark" but the job still shows the status `Suspended`. Specifically the `submit_tx` job shows a `null` value instead of the expected JSON string `{\"logs\": ...`

The [oracle contract](https://gist.github.com/e4208b8c5ef9ade70e5a9b1bab99059f) does not receive any transactions from the node and the [oracle consumer](https://gist.github.com/8a79759b0575895152de3288f9e4cf3f) does not receive data from the oracle contract.

The node wallet is funded with 0.001 ETH and both the consumer and oracle contract are funded with sufficient LINK for the requested operation given the asking price. Additionally, the node shows a single transaction to the oracle contract as `Ìn progress`

The log files show the following error:

```
2022-05-26T15:20:28.102Z [ERROR] Tx 0xREDACTED with type 0x0 was rejected due to insufficient eth. The eth node returned primary websocket (wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/0REDACTED) call failed: insufficient funds for gas * price + value. ACTION REQUIRED: Chainlink wallet with address 0xREDACTED is OUT OF FUNDS
```

Environment:

- Chainlink v1.3.0
- Brownie v1.18.1
- Solidity 0.8.7
- Network Rinkeby

I would expect the job's result to be submitted as a transaction to the oracle contract. Why is the job suspended despite sufficient funds for the gas fees?

Comment: Could you perhaps share a gist of your node's TOML job and also the client/consumer contracts calling function or working example? That may help reproduce.

Comment: Sure. Nothing special about these. 
toml: https://gist.github.com/ee3220bf57e8f4b366a439220f1627ce 
consumer: https://gist.github.com/8a79759b0575895152de3288f9e4cf3f 
oracle: https://gist.github.com/e4208b8c5ef9ade70e5a9b1bab99059f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `Suspended` is the new `Pending` [similar measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639935/chainlink-node-what-to-do-when-transactions-are-pending) help. Specifically, 0.0001 ETH is not enough funding even if the gas fees are lower than that.

Funding of 0.1 ETH seems to be an acceptable amount.